# Eleventy tags - convert to lowercase and sort alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, eleventy

I am using the tag filters from [eleventy-base-blog](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog):

```js
eleventyConfig.addFilter("getAllTags", collection => {
  let tagSet = new Set();
  for(let item of collection) {
    (item.data.tags || []).forEach(tag => tagSet.add(tag));
  }
  return Array.from(tagSet);
});

eleventyConfig.addFilter("filterTagList", function filterTagList(tags) {
  return (tags || []).filter(tag => ["all", "no-show"].indexOf(tag) === -1);
});
```

These work as expected. However, I would like to:

1. Transform tags to lowercase to minimize `Output Conflict` from tags like `JavaScript`, `Javascript`, and `javascript`.
2. Sort tags alphabetically for usability.

I stink at JS and after hours of trying, I must admit defeat. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I am not versed in the plugin, so not sure how this code is getting used down the road, but does changing `tagSet.add(tag)` to `tagSet.add(tag.toLowerCase())` and the `Array.from(tagSet)` to `Array.from(tagSet).sort()` make a difference ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - Yes! Thank you!. If you post this as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two points where you could make some adjustments.

First, when adding a tag to the set, you can covert to lowercase so that they are unique in the set

```
tagSet.add(tag.toLowerCase())
```

and when converting to an array and returning the tags, you can sort them

```
Array.from(tagSet).sort();
```

---

```js
eleventyConfig.addFilter("getAllTags", collection => {
  let tagSet = new Set();
  for(let item of collection) {
    (item.data.tags || []).forEach(tag => tagSet.add(tag.toLowerCase()));
  }
  return Array.from(tagSet).sort();
});
```